# The event onclick when trying to make ajax call not applied for all buttons have the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I`m trying to make ajax call that triggered by onclick event, So the first problem is the call not reach the URL given in request to manipulate data, but that return alert on success case !!

Call script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.summernote').summernote();

  $('#btn-req').click(function () {
    $.post('sendreq', {
        freelancerid: $('#freelid').val(),
        task: 'get_freelancer_id'
      },
      function (data) {
        alert("requested");
      }
    )
  });
});
```

The second problem is the event not applied on all buttons have the same id that just applied on first button!?

Any help please

Comment: Use `class` instead. Multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML. Bind using: `$('.my-class')...`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a `class` attribute for all the `button` elements that will make ajax requests:

```js
$('.btn-req').click(function () {
  console.log($(this).text(), 'was clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-req">Click Me!</button>
<button class="btn-req">Another button</button>
<button>And one more widout Ajax!</button>
```

Comment: it't work, the call makes for every buttons but the result I got not as I want, I have hidden checkbox whene the button is pressed I need to change parameter value to store it in database but all the result return the value of first chckbox I try to change id to class but didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('#btn-req').click(function ()
```

to

```
$('button[name="your_btn_name"]').click(function ()
```

Comment: it't work, the call makes for every buttons but the result I got not as I want, I have hidden checkbox whene the button is pressed I need to change parameter value to store it in database but all the result return the value of first chckbox I try to change id to class but didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

**the first question:**

The post request is succeed(back-end server returns a 200 status code) since the third parameter is called.You should check the back-end server log and confirm if the request is received, no matter whether the manipulation is failed or not.

**the second question:**

Ids with the same name is not allowed in html, only the first id will be valid.You should apply the same name class instead.